# Running Ryu Controller Problems

Tags: ubuntu, importerror, attributeerror, sdn, ryu

When I run ryu-manager after installing it, the following error appears to me:

**TypeError: cannot set 'is_timeout' attribute of immutable type 'TimeoutError'**

I searched how to solve this error and I found a way that tells me to use a newer version  of eventlet **pip install eventlet==0.33.1**  , when I use it another error appears:

**from eventlet.wsgi import  ALREADY HANDLED

ImportError cannot import name ALREADY HAndled from eventlet.wsgi**

I searched a lot and tried many solutions choices but I don't find anything helpful about this thing. What might be the problem?  I hope one can help me to solve this.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem because of Eventlet installation. Install Rio once again and avoid adding Python-Eventlet to the following code when installing Dependencies:

```
Sudo apt-get install python-eventlet python-routes python-webob python-paramiko python-dev
```